# Huge AJAX call duration difference between returning Content and PartialView

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following AJAX call:

```
function login() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Account/Login",
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divNotif').html(data);
        }
    });
};
```

And the following Account/Login action:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    return Content("Text changed!");    
}
```

Chrome's network console tells me this took `2.23s`.

However, changing it to

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Notifications/AccountDisabled.cshtml");         
}
```

the result is the ajax call takes `7.67s`.

The PartialView is nothing but a `.cshtml` with `Text changed!` in it.

What could be a possible cause for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, definitely didn't expect this. Moved view one folder up, to `~/Views/Home/AccountDisabled.cshtml`, and the call becomes

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Home/AccountDisabled.cshtml");
```

which results in a `2.26s` total AJAX call duration.

This seems at least weird to me, but well.. it got rid of my problem.